# meteor galaxy update node version

Tags: meteor, meteor-galaxy

Does anyone know what version of node is used by meteor galaxy?

I just tried to deploy and got the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
```

Therefore I assume that an old version of node is used.

The same code worked fine a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Each version of Meteor is linked to a given version of Node. Galaxy probably uses the one linked to your project. You can see which version it is by running `meteor node --version` within your project directory (on your local computer), and (potentially) update it by running `meteor update`.